# Angular 4 - How to remove attribute directive of other element by clicking on a button?

Tags: angular

I have added an attribute directive in the div element. Can I remove this by clicking on some button?

For example:

```
<div appDir [bgColor]="someDynamicColorValue" [innerHTML]="comment | trustHTML"><div>

<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

In the above sample code, can I remove attribute directive appDir (by setting with null value) by clicking on submit button?

Basically I want to disable all the functionalities which are associated with this directive.

Comment: try use [appDir]="variable" and toogle variable true|false

Comment: @Eliseo thank you for your response. appDir is the directive name in the Directive decoration like this `@Directive({ selector: '[appBox]' })` I have tried this, but this is not working, if I do like this then this will become an input field of this directive appDir. Although, I can add a flag in the code to make it not work. But, is there any good way to achieve this?

Comment: So why don't you just have two divs - one with the directive and one without and add an `*ngIf` to both divs and toggle between them using the button.

Comment: @chetan, I'm sorry, I read your question so fast. You can take the Chistophs solution or use directives with attributes like https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property